# Issue with accessing tableau dashboards whenever we trigger a batch job which uses pg_advisory_xact_lock function

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-9.3

The issue with accessing tableau dashboards whenever we trigger a batch job that uses the pg_advisory_xact_lock function

I have a parent schema named "Customer", every day a batch job gets triggered and it creates a child schema named "SME" and load the data to all the tables under the schema, at the end of the batch job there is a cleanup process happens, which packs all the tables under "SME" as a partition to "Customer" schema for this process, they have used pg_advisory_xact_lock function. During this batch job whenever the user accesses the tableau dashboards they experience a data load issue, is there an alternative way to do this above process apart from applying the pg_advisory_xact_lock function

Comment: What happens?  "A data load issue" doesn't convey any information.

Comment: Regardless of solution here you should upgrade your Postgres release. Version 9.3 reached end-of-life in Nov 2018, While not likely it is even possible a newer version may offer solutions not available in the older one.

Comment: The Postgres version is 12.11, I apologise for that. Apart from the pg_advisory_xact_lock function, is there any other solution I can use for the above issue, as specified in the below blog?                    
https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/